# Window opens outside of workspaces

Tags: release-hera, applications, window-management, window-manager, workspace

I use ElementaryOS 5.1. I first noticed the problem with Liferea, then with Libreoffice. Other applications (like Firefox and Thunderbird and the terminal) work fine.

The problem is:
When I open the application (e.g. Liferea) it opens somewhere in the far right where I cannot reach it. I use the windows button + arrow key right to go to the next workspace screen. There is always a last, empty screen. When I reach that and still click Windows button + arrow right, I see that there is another window which shows my application. But I don't know how to reach that.

I do have two screens connected to my tower, but I only use one. I suspected a problem with the second one, so I disabled it in the settings. Now it's disabled and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that indeed the problem was the second screen. Disabling it while the computer was running did not change anything and on restart the second screen was enabled again.
So I disconnected the cable to the second screen and restarted the computer - et volià, I see the applications on my screen.

Lessons learned: Don't have a second screen connected that you don't want to use anyway.